# What is wrong with jquery Ajax?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json

I am using Jquery ajax to receive information from the database. I test server side method.It work properly .  when the call in the page was an error json:
Message: "Invalid JSON primitive: }."

StackTrace:

"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDe  serializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer) 
depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)     at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializ  er.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)     at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializ  er.Deserialize[T](String input)     at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParam  sFromPostRequest(HttpContext context, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)     at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParam  s(WebServiceMethodData methodData, HttpContext context)     at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebS  erviceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)"

ExceptionType:"System.ArgumentException"

method sode is :

```
[WebMethod]
   public static  ParentDataT_book.OptionBook[] SearchNameBook(string nameBook, int state)
   {
       var bookBusiness = new T_bookBusiness();
       return bookBusiness.GetList(nameBook, (byte)0).ToArray();
    }
```

jquery ajax code is :

```
function searchBook() {
          j.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "Default.aspx/SearchNameBook",     //نام صفحه و متد
              data: "{'nameBook': '" + j('#ContentPlaceHolder1_txt_nameBook').val() + "', 'state': '" + j('#states').val() - 1 + "'}",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              dataType: "json",
              success: function (msg) {
                  var delay = function () {
                      AjaxSucceededSearch(msg);
                  };
                  setTimeout(delay, 1500); //remove this
              },
              error: AjaxFailedSearch
          });
          //});
      };
      // });
      function AjaxSucceededSearch(data) {
          if (result.d != null) {
              alert("data is  found!!!");
          }
          else
              if (result.d == null) {
                  alert("data is  not found!!!");
              }
      }
      function AjaxFailedSearch(result) {
          alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
      }
```

Friends Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: In console show this message :"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost:1036/WebSite_DadVaSetad/Default.aspx/SearchNameBook".

Comment: Using IinternetExplorer's F12 Tools / "Network", you can check if the JSON you are sending to the server is correct. Also, you could try to remove the ' for the state value as in 'state': " + j('#states').val() - 1 + "}", in order to serialize it as number

Comment: I use this code : data: { nameBook: j('#ContentPlaceHolder1_txt_nameBook').val(), state: (parseInt(j('#states').val()) - 1) }    .my browser is firefox.I have firebug in it.Is possible do it with firebug?

Comment: Sure, use the "Net" panel in Firebug and reload you page. you should then see all requests made to your page.

Comment: I debug the jquery and know that when run (success: function(result) ) go to function AjaxFailedSearch(result)  then show this error:TypeError: result is undefined

Comment: Not sure I understand you. Have a look at this: http://wiki.openiam.com/display/IAMSUITEV3/Using+Firebug+for+Inspecting+REST+Requests+and+Responses   this should help you checking what you are posting to the server

Comment: Why there is a 'j(#ContentPlaceHolder1_txt_nameBook).val()?It should be $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txt_nameBook").val()

Comment: If you use (var j = jQuery.noConflict();)  in place of codes : j worked insted $

Comment: I visited  wiki.openiam.com/display/IAMSUITEV3/… . it is helpful .In NET/XHR tab : post searchNameBook have error--->500 Internal Server Error       &          In post tab sended values are nameBook=hmah&state=14  ---->that is right     &   In Json tab was an error : -----> "Invalid JSON primitive: nameBook."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final code is :

```
  function searchBook() {
        var stateVal = (parseInt(j('#states').val()) - 1);
        var nameBookkVal = j('#ContentPlaceHolder1_txt_nameBook').val();
        j.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/SearchNameBook",     //نام صفحه و متد
            data: "{'nameBook':'"+nameBookkVal+"','state':'"+stateVal+"'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                var delay = function () {
                    AjaxSucceededSearch(result);
                };
                setTimeout(delay, 1500); //remove this
            },
            error: AjaxFailedSearch()
        });
        };
  function AjaxSucceededSearch(result) {
        if (result.d != null) {
            alert("data is  found!!!");
        }
        else
            if (result.d == false) {
                alert("data is not  found!!!");
            }
    }
    function AjaxFailedSearch(jqXhr, textStates , errorThrown) {
       // alert(errorThrown + ' ' + textStates);

    }
```

note:I delete the spaces characters in Data row.Now
This code worked correctly.Thank you for answering.